# How to Make Program Stop after Number of Iterations

Tags: arduino

So, I have my program here, I am trying to make a program that, we manually pull the wire out and place it back, each time I pull it out, it is 1 iteration and placing it back in is 1 iteration. Whenever it is connected to the port the external LED is dark, when it is pulled out, the external LED is bright. I should be able to do this for 10 iterations and stop once I get there.

The problem is, when I include the while(true); statement in, my external LED does not work, but without the statement in there, the program runs the way I want except that it does not stop working after 10 iterations, any help is appreciated!

```
#include<EEPROM.h>
const int LED = 12;
const int SWITCH = 4;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);           //LED is always outputting information
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);   //Built in LED is always outputting information
  pinMode(SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);  //Switch inputs value when in/out of ground
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int addr = 0;     //Declaring variables
  int count = 0;
  int seconds;

  if (digitalRead(SWITCH) == LOW) {             //If wire starts in ground, record values
    Serial.println("----Recording----");

    while (count <= 10) {                       //While count value is less than or equal to 10
      if (digitalRead(SWITCH) == LOW) {         //When wire is connected to 4
        count = count + 1;                      //Add one to count in each iteration
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);                 //LED light is off in this position
        delay(50);                              //Checks switch state every 0.05 seconds
      }
      else if (digitalRead(SWITCH) == HIGH) {   //When wire isnt connected to 4
        count = count + 1;                      //Add one to count in each iteration
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);                //LED light is on in this position
        delay(50);                              //Checks switch state every 0.05 seconds
      }
          while (true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it should be placed inside of that `while (count <= 10)` loop

Comment: I tried moving the position of it, but that didn't change anything

Comment: Have you tried to swap it with the next line? Also I don't think you'd notice. It'd work for 500ms and then it stops.

Comment: It has worked beforehand without the while(true); statement...that is just there to check the state of the switch every 0.05 seconds, so i'm not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Why it's not working? Let's rewrite your code a little:

```
    while (count <= 10) {
      count = count + 1;
      digitalWrite(LED, digitalRead(SWITCH));
      delay(50);

      while (true); // aaand kill it
    }
```

I'm ommiting the race condition if the first digital read returns HIGH and then the second returns LOW (it wouldn't wait for 50ms to stop)

I'd expect something like counting on pin change or so:

```
    while (count <= 10) {
      byte = digitalRead(SWITCH);
      if (byte != digitalRead(LED))
      { 
        count = count + 1;
        digitalWrite(LED, byte);
      }
      delay(50);
    }
    while (true); // aaand kill it
```

Comment: So would it only be the bottom code, that would run in my loop? Or am I replacing it for some other part of my code?

Comment: @Thomas Well, if you set the LED to HIGH before entering counting loop, then it would be all